# Javascript algorithm to restore purchases

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am trying do do a calculation I am finding a little difficult. For those maths boffs out there, please can you assist.

**Background**

I am building a mobile app, where a user can subscribe to a service for a given period (i.e. 3 days, 10 days, 30 days, 731 days).

Now, for example, if they subscribe for 3 days, and after 2 days, they subscribe for a further 10 days, their subscription will expire 11 days from now.

e.g.

```
=== 3 ===>
       === 10 ===>  | expires 13 days from the purchase date
```

**Issue**

I need to be able to restore a persons subscriptions at any given point in time.

For example, if a user logs on with a new devise, I need to be able to restore their subscription to its current state.

**Solution**

I can do so with an existing `restore` function.

This function returns a list of all products ever purchased by the user. Each purchase contains:

- `productId` - which matches the product (i.e. 3 days, 10 days, 30
  days, 731 days)
- `date` - timestamp of the purchase

I need to write a function to calculate the users current subscription state at a given point in time. If their historic purchases have expired they are ignored, but if a purchase is still valid, it must be accumulated to the subscription total.

e.g.

```
=== 3 ===>
        === 10 ===>     | expired
                             === 3 ===>
                                     === 3 ===>  | expires
```

(I am using the [following api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase))

**My Attempt**

```
  public PRODUCT_IDS: string[] = ['3days', '10days', '30days', '2years'];
  public PRODUCT_DAYS: number[] = [3, 10, 30, 731];

  private restore(): void {
    this.iap.restorePurchases().then((purchases: any[]) => {
      var currentDateMilliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
      let subDate: number = 0;
      for (let i: number = 0; i < purchases.length; i++) {
        let productid: string = purchases[i];
        let purchaseDate: number = purchases[i].date;
        if (productid && purchaseDate) {
          for (let j: number = 0; j < this.PRODUCT_IDS.length; j++) {
            if (productid === this.PRODUCT_IDS[j]) {
              let prodMilis = this.PRODUCT_DAYS[j] * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
              let tempDate: number = purchaseDate + prodMilis;
              if (tempDate - currentDateMilliseconds > 0) {
                subDate += tempDate - currentDateMilliseconds;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.personModel.contactable = subDate;
    });
  }
```

As you can see, this is incomplete.

I am trying to populate the the variable `subDate` with the total accumulated subscription expiry date.

**Question**

If anyone can assist me to complete this function, I would greatly appreciate their help.

**More info**

```
  .restorePurchases()
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    /*
      [{
        transactionId: ...
        productId: ...
        state: ...
        date: ...
      }]
    */
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

[ref](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase)

**test data**

```
  private restorePurchases(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => {
      let data: any[] =
        [
          {
            productId: '3days',
            date: 1499841497305
          },
          {
            productId: '10days',
            date: 1499841498305
          },
          {
            productId: '3days',
            date: 14998414979305
          }
        ];

      resolve(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a `purchases` JSON example ?

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the feedback.  I will be back home in 10 min and will reply.

Comment: @Nathan, I added a `More info` section above with an example of the returned JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given (sorted by purchase date)

```
Date  Purchase
1000  3
1002  10
2000  3
2001  3
```

Expect end date of 2006.0

Iterate, accumulating days where overlapping:

```
Date  Days CumulEnd  OverlapId  
1000  3    1003      0
1002  10   1013      0
2000  3    2003      1
2001  3    2006      1
```

So the key algorithm is:

1. Sort on purchase date
2. Accumulate days where the purchase date is inside the cumulative period for the overlap

If you had a data structure like `[{ date: 1000, days: 3 }, { date: 1002, days: 10 }]`, then an accumulator might work like this:

```
function collectOverlaps(accumulator, currentElem, currentIndex, array) {
   var currDate = currentElem.date;
   // if no previous overlaps or does not overlap last, create new
   if(accumulator.length == 0 || 
     currDate > accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end) {
      accumulator.push({ start: currDate, end: currDate + currentElem.days });
   } else { // extend overlap
      accumulator[accumulator.length - 1].end += currentElem.days;
   }
   return accumulator;
}
```

Then we can accumulate the overlaps thus:

```
// overlaps will contain { start: x, end: y }
var overlaps = purchases.reduce(collectOverlaps, []);
```

Example:

```
var purchases = [{date: 1000, days:3}, {date: 1002, days:10}, {date:2000, days:3}, {date:2001, days:3}];
var overlaps = purchases.reduce(collectOverlaps, []);
console.log(collectOverlaps);
```

Produces:

```
[[object Object] {
  end: 1013,
  start: 1000
}, [object Object] {
  end: 2006,
  start: 2000
}]
```

You could make this even simpler by throwing away overlaps that are no longer valid, but this way at least you get a complete set of contiguous licensed periods.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, this is the solution I am using:

```
  private restore(): void {
    this.restorePurchases().then((purchases: any[]) => {
      purchases.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
      // console.log(purchases);
      var currentDateMilliseconds = 1499872296134; // replace with //(new Date).getTime();
      // console.log("current time: " + moment(currentDateMilliseconds).fromNow() + '   ' + currentDateMilliseconds);
      let runningTotal: number = 0;
      for (let i: number = 0; i < purchases.length; i++) {
        let productid: string = purchases[i].productId;
        let purchaseDate: number = purchases[i].date;
        if (productid && purchaseDate) {
          // console.log('');
          // console.log(productid + " purchaseDate: " + moment(purchaseDate).fromNow() + '   ' + purchaseDate);
          for (let j: number = 0; j < this.PRODUCT_IDS.length; j++) {
            if (productid === this.PRODUCT_IDS[j]) {
              let prodMilis = this.PRODUCT_DAYS[j] * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
              let prodExpiryDate: number = purchaseDate + prodMilis;
              // console.log('prodMilis: ' + prodMilis + ' ['+this.PRODUCT_DAYS[j]+']  (' + ((prodMilis) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + ' days)');
              // console.log('Product expiary date: ' + moment(prodExpiryDate).fromNow() + '   ' + prodExpiryDate);
              let timeAdded: number = 0;
              if (runningTotal === 0) {
                timeAdded = prodExpiryDate - currentDateMilliseconds;
              } else {
                timeAdded = prodMilis;
              }
              if (timeAdded > 0) {
                // console.log('timeAdded: ' + timeAdded + '  (' + ((timeAdded) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + ' days)');
                runningTotal += timeAdded;
                // console.log('Running total: ' + runningTotal + '  (' + (runningTotal / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + ' days)');
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // console.log('');
      // console.log("final subDate: " + moment(currentDateMilliseconds + runningTotal).fromNow());
      this.personModel.contactable = runningTotal;
      this.personService.savePerson(this.personModel).then((person: PersonModel) => {
        this.personModel = person;
      });
    });
  }

  private restorePurchases(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => {
      let data: any[] =
        [
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.30days',
            date: 1439871932828
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
            date: 1499441932828
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.10days',
            date: 1499751932828
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.10days',
            date: 1499751942849
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
            date: 1499751932824
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.3days',
            date: 1499751930829
          },
          {
            productId: 'com.thewhozoo.prod.message.30days',
            date: 1499861932829
          }
        ];

      resolve(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Some issues in this code. `timeAdded = prodExpiryDate - currentDateMilliseconds;` will add on different amounts at different times. If you bought 3 days and 1 day in bought another 10 days, on day 2 the 10 days should count as 10, not 9; i.e. I don't think it's handling overlaps correctly. Do you have unit tests?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the feedback. The `timeAdded` is only calculated like that when `runningTotal === 0`, i.e. for the first purchase that has not expired. Thereafter, it is calculated as `timeAdded = prodMilis`. This is valid because the first purchase could be partially expired.

Comment: My test data is the data returned from the `restorePurchases()` function.

Comment: Do you think the above is a problem?

Comment: Ah yes, I misread that bit. I do think the logic could be better, but it seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will do some more test cases.